# How to add selected attribute when selecting an option?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a select in which I add an option dynamically, depending on the number of elements in the database. How can I add a selected attribute on selection so that the user's selection can be tracked

```js
function generateBanks(banks) {
  banks.forEach((bank) => {
    const bank_option = document.createElement("option");
    bank_option.value = bank.bankName;
    bank_option.text = bank.bankName;
    bankSelect.appendChild(bank_option);
  });
}
```

```js
function getAllBanks() {
  db.collection("banks").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
    let banks = [];
    snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
      const bank = {
        id: change.doc.id,
        ...change.doc.data(),
      };
      banks.push(bank);
      generateBanks([bank]);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding if you want to use a cookie to store that information or you want to take it from the db. Can you please explain better with an example?

Comment: I get a collection of banks from Firestore and add it to select so that the user can select the desired bank. I need to keep track of which option is selected so that I can calculate the payment with the right data in the right bank

Comment: Together with the name of the bank, its data is stored in the database so that later it is possible to calculate the payment. And I need to take the correct data when choosing a bank

Comment: So do you want to take an `id` of a bank, thanks to the option selected, and use it to query the db to get the necessary data to use the calculation, am I right?

Comment: I want to get the bank id due to the selected option in order to substitute the data in the formula. Each bank has its own data, I want to somehow make it so that when choosing from the select bank, the payment amount changes, because. each bank has different numbers

Comment: I need to somehow keep track of the selection in the select in order to write the desired formula

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding correctly what you asked, you can have an `id` as `value` of each `option` of the `select` element. For a better explanation I'll show a little example:

```js
let payment = document.getElementById('payment');
const calculate_button = document.getElementById('calculate-button');
const bank_select = document.getElementById('bank-select');

calculate_button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const bank_id_selected = bank_select.value;

    // Do a query to your db with the `bank_id_selected`, here substituited by a `random()`
    let payment_amount = Math.random();

    payment.textContent = 'You are going to pay: ' + payment_amount;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="selection-div">
        <select id="bank-select" name="Bank">
            <option value="BankId1">Bank1</option>
            <option value="BankId2">Bank2</option>
            <option value="BankId3">Bank3</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p id="payment">You are going to pay: </p>
        <button id="calculate-button">Calculate</button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't have an option in my html, I add them dynamically, depending on the number of elements in the database

Comment: And what element are you using exactly? Because, I see you are generating an `option` element in `const bank_option = document.createElement("option");`

Comment: I only have <select id="bank-select"></select>. It is empty and I dynamically add option

Comment: Ok, that's fine. The important thing is that you add a `value` attribute to your dynamically generated `option`. For the rest, it should be a similar situation of my example. Are you able to do that with your current setup?

Answer (score 0):

When a user selects an option from the dropdown, the "selected" attribute will automatically be added to the  element in the DOM. From there, you'll need to have your code retrieve the user's selected option from the dropdown when calculating the payment like so...

First, get the dropdown options:

`const bankOptions = document.getElementById('banks');`

Second, set the 'selectedBank' variable to the user's selected option:

`const selectedBank = bankOptions.value;`

Comment: I added an id for my select and in the console log I try to display the selectedBank, but it does not display anything, it's just empty

Comment: Have you set the dropdown id attribute to `id = "banks"`?